# HTML Entity for new line not working in IE10

Tags: html, entity

As the title says i'm trying

```
&#013;
&#010;
```

for new lines in a buttons text but in IE10 it doesn't show, I can change the mode to IE9 and it does show. Ironically in View Source it shows as well it's just not rendered in the display.  Any ideas I can't find a solution for 2 hours :)

This is an asp.net button using the following markup

```
<asp:Button ID="imgViewQuoteDocument" runat="server" Text="View Quote&#010;Document" ToolTip="View Quote Document" OnClientClick="return confirm_close();" />
```

It renders correctly in all browsers except IE10 which removes the entity reference but instead of inserting a new line just simply removes the reference leaving the buttons text as

"View QuoteDocument"

instead of

"Vew Quote
Document"

p.s. you do not need examples to answer why IE10 ignores HTML Entities, you either know because you've come across it before or you don't know. The site has degraded somewhat over the years.

Comment: Please show your code and try to explain better. Noone will understand what is 'new lines in a buttons text'

Comment: Most people should understand a button in a browser and the text value being the text on the button. The title says it all though for some reason the HTML Entity for a new line is ignored by IE10. The post has removed the new line entities I posted which I find ironic

Comment: Specifically the problem is the HTML Entity reference is ignored in IE10. Unfortunately <br /> doesn't work as .net kindly parses your text values so what you type in the IDE actually comes through. It's quite frustrating as it works in Chrome, Firefox, IE 8, 9, 11 and Safari. Just IE10 is ignoring it and the entity references are used throughout the markup.

Comment: The question does not show *any* HTML code, only ASP code (and is not tagged with “asp”). You should show what the generated HTML is.

Comment: I used this site a few years ago and it was very helpful. I see now it's full of idiots, no offence the question is very very simple.  Why is IE10 ignoring HTML Entities. It's not relevant to the markup the fact is IE10 is ignoring the HTML Entity where as 8,9 11 and other browsers do not.  Please get a grip on reality (it's asp.net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make either entity work as expected if you put it in a <pre> tag.

The <pre> tag is for preformatted text, so it will attempt to display normal plaintext conventions like newlines, multiple spaces, and so on...

I personally like to use the <pre> tag in conjunction with:

```
white-space: pre-line;
```

for more normal content box wrapping - but it will depend on your application I imagine...

example: https://jsfiddle.net/mhouser_nowmediagroup/m3ywpLj0/

Answer (score 0):

In html there is no difference between a space, a tab and a new line. It is just whitespace. A break is achieved by the tag <br>.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate the input I will of course find a solution elsewhere.