# HTML entity for new line for name property of HTML tag

Tags: html, space, primereact

I have similar usecase as mentioned in [HTML Entity for new line not working in IE10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23264876/html-entity-for-new-line-not-working-in-ie10/76053274)

`<Column columnKey="status" header="Status" body={status} style={{ width: '150px', textAlign: "center" }} headerTooltipOptions={{event:"both", hideDelay: 1000 }} headerTooltip="Status for non-leaf nodes: count of healthy, unhealthy, warning and missing leaf nodes. &#10; &#13; Status for leaf nodes: health status."/>`

The tooltip text need to have new line. I tried adding `&#10; &#13;` but it is not working.. I came across pre tag. But i am not sure about its usage.

I am using primereact. Column api : https://primereact.org/treetable/#api.Column

How to use pre in such scenario?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added below `const` and used it as reference

```
const tooltiptext = "Status for non-leaf nodes: count of healthy, unhealthy, warning and missing leaf nodes.\nStatus for leaf nodes: health status."
```

and used above as reference:

```
<Column columnKey="status" header="Status" body={status} style={{ width: '150px', textAlign: "center" }} headerTooltipOptions={{event:"both", hideDelay: 1000 }} headerTooltip={tooltiptext}/>
```